# prevent duplicate ajax calls from bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In a bootstrap modal, when the user presses Enter, an ajax call is triggered,

```
$('#amount').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13) {
        $( "#final" ).trigger( "click" ); // this triggers the ajax call
    }

});
```

But if accidentally if a user presses the enter key for long, too many submissions are made and thus, unwanted records are entered in the database. How do I stop this unexpected behaviour? Are there any best practices in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's a best practice or not, but i would do this way

```
window.alreadySubmit = false;
$('#amount').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13 && !alreadySubmit) {
        window.alreadySubmit = true;
        $( "#final" ).trigger( "click" ); // this triggers the ajax call
    }

});
```

then in your ajax success callback reset the `windowd.alreadySubmit` variable to `false`

alernatively you can just set a timeout, like this:

```
var myTimeout = 3000; //ms = 3 seconds
window.alreadySubmit = false;

$('#amount').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==13 && !alreadySubmit) {
        window.alreadySubmit = true;
        $( "#final" ).trigger( "click" ); // this triggers the ajax call
        setTimeout(function(){ window.alreadySubmit = false; }, myTimeout);
    }

});
```

Comment: your solution works. but I what if I want to use this event again after sometime? Your possible suggestion would be to add `window.alreadySubmit = false;` after my ajax call is executed. I tried this but the problem still persists. and still a duplicate record is entered if I long press the Enter key.

Comment: @RameshPareek well, that code enable the submit once the previous call was done, so if the ajax call is executed quickly you can notice duplicated records. To avoid that check my updated answer

Comment: that did the trick! setting it to 1000ms is sufficient. please consider upvotng the question if you think it'll help future visitors.